# How to convert a json to a a proper table in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I created a Power BI Custom Data Connector, the idea is to be able to connect to SSRS Dataset using this Custom Data Connector I was able to do it but the resulting formatted json is different from what i expect.

Here's the result when I open the Custom Connector in Power BI, I expected a properly formatted table but the result is not.

[image: Power BI]

Columns are List of Record contain the Column Names and Type 
[image: Power BI]

While the Row is a List of List containing the values for CustomerID and CustomerName.

[image: Power Bi]

Here's my code.

```
section Test.PQ.SSRS_Connector;

[DataSource.Kind="Asia.PQ.SSRS_Connector", Publish="Test.PQ.SSRS_Connector.Publish"]
shared Test.PQ.SSRS_Connector.Feed = Value.ReplaceType(SSRSConImpl, type function (url as Uri.Type) as any);

DefaultRequestHeaders = [
     #"Accept" = "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",  
     #"OData-MaxVersion" = "4.0"

];

SSRSConImpl = (url as text) =>
    let
        body= "",
        source = Web.Contents(url, [ Headers = DefaultRequestHeaders, Content=Text.ToBinary(body)]),
        json = Json.Document(source)
    in 
        json;
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting some sample JSON would be helpful, but based on the screenshots it seems like continuing your function as below may work:

```
// ... Your function code
json = Json.Document(source),
toTable = Table.FromRows(json[Rows], {"CustomerID", "CustomerName"}) // If there are more columns, consider extracting names dynamically from json[Columns]
// .... Any remaining code
```

Code is untested.